# Probability using the normal distribution

Tags: statistics

Four weeks in a row the maintenance times of a group of machines per week were recorded .Assume that the time spent on maintenance of a group of machines  per week is approximately normally distributed with mean 4hours and standard deviation 1.25 hours.

What is the probability that the four-week average maintenance time  will be between 3.5 and 4.5 hours ?

My turn :-
$P(3.5<X<4.5) = P(\frac{3.5-4}{1.25} <Z<\frac{4.5 -4}{1.25} $
= $P(-0.4 < Z < 0.4 )  = 0.312$

Is this answer correct ?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I don´t think that this is correct. I have $P(-0.8<Z<0.8)=0.684$